# jquery effects not working on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


function slidedown(id){

$('#rerooftext').hide(0);
$('#inspectiontext').hide(0);
$('#remodelingtext').hide(0);
$('#restorationstext').hide(0);
$('#commtext').hide(0);
$('#painttext').hide(0);

setTimeout(300);
$('#'+id.id+'text').fadeToggle(1000);

};
</script>
```

Here I have a function that hides several divs that contain text, and then show the div for the clicked link, using jquery functions.  This code works great in chrome, but internet explorer does not perform the animation, when I click the link it hides the current div which is reroof but fails to show the new div, which is the code $('#'+id.id+'text').fadeToggle(1000);

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Which version of IE? 2.0? 6? 7?

Comment: How is the function called?  What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Seems to me like a script error on 'setTimeout(300);' and so the following animation fails. IE is not as forgiving as Chrome.

Comment: Also, seeing your html + css would be helpful, since IE might be tripping over float bugs or absolutely/relatively positioned elements.

Comment: your usage of settimeout is wrong, check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Then, can you test with  $('#'+id.id+'text').show(), then  $('#'+id.id+'text').show(1000) ?

Comment: @SKS ie8 tolerate setTimeout(300); 300 is converted as "300" which, while doing nothing, is valid javascript. but haven't tested with other versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because there is a bug in your code at `setTimeout(300);` because of which execution does not reach till the line where you perform fade animation.

`setTimeout` takes 2 arguments. First is the function pointer or a string containing the code to execute, second argument is the time in milliseconds after which the specified function or code to execute.

Comment that line because it is useless and try it will work. If you want to delay the animation for some time you can take a look at jQuery [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

```
function slidedown(id){

   $('#rerooftext').hide(0);
   $('#inspectiontext').hide(0);
   $('#remodelingtext').hide(0);
   $('#restorationstext').hide(0);
   $('#commtext').hide(0);
   $('#painttext').hide(0);

   //setTimeout(300);

    $('#'+id.id+'text').fadeToggle(1000);

};
```

Comment: in which IE version does setTimeout( 300 ) fails ?

Comment: I think in all IE versions(at least < IE9 I tested) with error (Invalid argument). I see it failing even in FF with similar error. But in `Chrome` it works fine without throwing any error.